# Css div alignment

Tags: css

I am trying to render HTML select box.
I have 3 Div's inside table cell.
        
           Value

When the table expands the alignment of leftDiv and rightDiv is OK. But when
the table shrinks below the size of two divs (leftDiv & rightDiv ) the rightDiv is rendering below the leftDiv.

How to make this two Divs stick together all the time?

Comment: Do you mean 3 or 2 Divs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have few choices:

1. Have the 2 divs width set as relative or percentage (say 50% or 4x%)
2. Have the table cell (td)'s minimum width set as that or more of the 2 child divs.
   `min-width: xxxx;`

There are probably a few more methods you can google for.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the width of leftDiv & rightDiv with percentage, not pixels

```
.leftDiv {width: 50%}
.rightDiv {width: 50%}
```

Comment: It works for the problem but i want the rightDiv to be right aligned all the time

Answer (score 0):

Set white-space:nowrap on the on the table cell. And white-space: normal on the divs themselves.

```
td.myClass {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
#leftDiv , #rightDiv { whitespace: normal }
```

Answer (score 0):

Or this, if your table cell is a fixed width (100px in my example):

```
.leftDiv{width:50px;float:left;}
.rightDiv{width:50px;float:right;}
```